# VMWare ESXi trying to connect to IP on different subnet

Tags: networking, vmware-esxi, vmware-vsphere

Our VMWare ESXi host is sending VMWare Server requests (port 902) every five or so seconds to a private IP address that is not in the subnet.

For reference, the ESXi server is on a Class B address and it's trying to connect to a Class C address.  I only discovered this after reviewing firewall traffic logs for another issue.

Where do I go to find out why this is occurring?

Comment: The VCenter agent installed in the past ?

Comment: Do an nslookup against the IP address, see what it is - oh and I'm going to upvote you for using 'class-B/C', not heard those terms for over a decade, bless... :)

Comment: I forgot to mention the address it tries to hit is private - so it's not routable.  The firewall just drops it. @yagmoth555 To my knowledge there's never been a VCenter server or agent installed

Comment: Is that IP a VM? If so this is normal behavior, there is a post on VMware site about this. If I can find the link I will post it here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An old config from a vcenter agent must still be there in the esxi, as please see the fact there : [Required ports for VMware vCenter Server 5.5 (2051575)](https://kb.vmware.com/selfservice/microsites/search.do?language=en_US&cmd=displayKC&externalId=2051575)

> **902**
>
> TCP/UDP
>
> This is the default port used by the vCenter Server system to send
>   data to managed hosts. **Managed hosts also send a regular heartbeat
>   over UDP port 902 to the vCenter Server system**. This port must not be
>   blocked by firewalls between the server and the hosts or between
>   hosts.

Please follow that KB to remove any trace from Vcenter : 
[Uninstalling vpxa in ESXi (1005482)](https://kb.vmware.com/selfservice/microsites/search.do?language=en_US&cmd=displayKC&externalId=1005482)

To uninstall the vpxa agent:

> 1.From the main yellow and gray screen on the ESXi host, press Alt-F1.
>
> 2.At the next screen, type:
>
> unsupported
>
> 3.When prompted, enter the root password.
>
> 4.Execute the following command:
>
> /opt/vmware/uninstallers/VMware-vpxa-uninstall.sh
>
> Note: The vpxa agent automatically re-installs once the ESXi host is
>   connected to vCenter Server.

Comment: I don't have that script in my system.  Running 'ls /opt/vmware' returns only the folder 'vpxa', which is empty.

Comment: @IAmTheSquidward Confirm me your version of ESX, I will check in my lab if I can find the config file related to vpxa

Comment: ESXi 5.5.0, 1331820

Comment: @IAmTheSquidward On my 5.5's host, the file was there; /etc/vmware/vpxa/, vpxa.cfg and the ip is in a <serverIp> header.

Comment: Very interesting.  That file is blank.

Comment: @IAmTheSquidward Host restarted ? Could be a old configuration still in memory

Comment: So, looks like it was a cached entry.  It's been three years of uptime, which is before I took over administration, so I didn't know about it!  Restarting the vpxa service fixed it altogether.